# Nonlinear discrete time systems

Tags: nonlinear-system, discrete-optimization

Is it possible for discrete-time parameter $a(k)$ with an update rule like
$a(k+1)=f(a(k))$    &   always  $|f(a(k))|<= c|a(k)|$  where $0<c<0.5$
to converge from the initial value $c_1$ to final value $c_2$, where $c_1>c_2>1$? (I mean: is it possible for such a discrete parameter $a(k)$ with mentioned condition not to converge to zero?If yes,I need an example of such update rule.

Comment: Can you see that $a(k)<c_1c^k$?

Comment: yes, but we can not ignore $1<c_2<a(k)<c_1$

Comment: "is it possible for such a discrete parameter a(k) with mentioned condition not to converge to zero?" No, because $|a_k|\leqslant c_1c^k\to0$.